# Convert DateTime? to string

Tags: c#

I want to convert a `DateTime?` to string. If a date is null then return `""`, else return a string format like this: `"2020-03-05T07:52:59.665Z"`. The code is something like this but it won't work. It said `"DateTime?"` do not contain a definition for "ToUniversalTime". Someone know how to fix this?

```
DateTime? date = DateTime.UtcNow;

var dateInUTCString = date == null ? "" : date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
```

Comment: By the way, do you just want `.ToString("o")`?

Comment: Oh, I already use DateTime.UTCNow so I don't need to use ToUniversalTime() anymore? @John. Ah I see, `.ToString("o")`, I'll research more. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, and assuming you just want an ISO8601 format, you can use "o". See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip)

Comment: @John: "o" uses tick precision, which may not be desirable even though it's ISO-8601 compliant.

Comment: When it `DateTime`, return to client it auto parse to string with `Z` at the end of string. But when I use `.ToString("o")`, it doesn't have `Z`. So `DateTime?.ToString("o")` not consistency with another `DateTime`

Comment: "But when I use .ToString("o"), it doesn't have Z" - it will if you still call ToUniversalTime(); the 'Z' comes from it having a Kind of UTC.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `DateTime?` have the `Value` property and the `HasValue` property

Try:

```cs
var dateInUTCString = date.HasValue ? date.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'") : "";
```

You can use a short version:

```cs
var dateInUTCString = date?.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'") ?? "";
```

Answer (score 9):

While you can use the `Value` property directly as per Leszek's answer, I'd probably use the null-conditional operator in conjunction with the null-coalescing operator:

```cs
string dateInUTCString =
    date?.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
    ?? "";
```

Here the `?.` will just result in a null value if `date` is null, and the `??` operator will provide a default value if the result of the `date?.ToUniversalTime().ToString(...)` call is null (which would only happen if `date` is null).

Note that you really want to specify the invariant culture to avoid getting unexpected results when the current thread's culture doesn't use the Gregorian calendar, and you don't need to quote all those literals in the format string. It certainly *works* when you do so, but it's harder to read IMO.

If you don't mind how much precision is expressed in the string, you can make the code simpler using the ["O" standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip):

```cs
string dateInUTCString = date?.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O") ?? "";
```

At that point you don't need to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as that's *always* used by "O".

Comment: Why not use `"O"` as a format string?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip

Comment: @ZoharPeled: That has tick precision, and the OP apparently only wants millisecond precision.

Comment: Actually I want a format that have `Z` at the end of string

Comment: @camahe: The "O" format specifier already uses that - see the documentation link that Zohar posted. If you really don't mind how many digits of precision you get, using "O" would be a lot simpler - you wouldn't need to specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in that case either. Will amend the answer to add that as an option.

Comment: Ah, I know what I want, `ToString("u")` =)))) thank you everyone

Comment: @camahe: So you don't need *any* subsecond precision? And you don't need the "T" in the middle?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I need the "T", but the team decided that we don't need that "T" anymore, just the "Z" =)))

Comment: @camahe: Please take a lesson from this that when you ask a question, it helps to be *really* precise in your requirements.